# Why is Chinese text displaying strangely?

Tags: 12.04, fonts, chinese

I just upgraded to 12.04 and should have pretty default settings, yet Chinese text is displaying inconsistently. In the example below, for instance, 九 and 山 (two out of three characters) look as expected, but 龙 looks like it's in a different font, or is boldfaced, or is somehow antialiased differently than the others. Why does this happen, and how can I fix it?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

it is indeed a different font. the fonts you are using do not include that character, so Ubuntu switched to one that contain that font. to fix this ~ switch to font that include all the character you need.

Comment: Please edit your answer to add how can one switch to another font.

Answer (score 0):

To get the nice fonts, install the Language Support for Chinese Simplified/Traditional, like what is described in this guide: http://pinyinjoe.com/linux/ubuntu-12-chinese-setup.htm

As an aside, iirc several versions back the Chinese text will just show up as ???, so in a way whatever fallback font that is being used now (some said it was Dejavu) can be considered an improvement since that time.